# Python 3 replacing letters

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with replacing letters in python 3

**Error mesg:**

> line 24, in 
>       repl = capitalWord[1:] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I really was trying to figure out the issue but I really got frustrated.

```
Code:
#----------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------------------------
#function to print the numbers and prime numbers
#-----------------------------------------------
import re
inStr = input('Enter input string: ')

# split word separated by sapce in enetered sentence
words = inStr.split(' ')

# traverse list of words anf find capitalized word
capitalWord = None
for word in words:
    if word.isupper()==True:
        capitalWord = word


# replace * with remaining letters of
#capital word after skipping first character

repl = capitalWord[1:]
inStr = re.sub('[*]',repl,inStr)

# join all words with space again and print them
print ('Output sentence :')
print (inStr)
```

Comment: check for None before repl = capitalWord[1:]

Comment: I did not get what do u mean ?

Comment: Use: `if capitalWord:
 repl = capitalWord[1:]
 inStr = re.sub('[*]',repl,inStr)

 # join all words with space again and print them
 print ('Output sentence :')
 print (inStr)`

Comment: In line 24 you are getting error because the variable capitalWord is None. Check for this condition before splicing capitalWord.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did it but now it give me this error                                        inStr = re.sub('[*]',repl,inStr)
NameError: name 'repl' is not defined

Comment: @venkat I am a beginner how can I fix it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
inStr = input('Enter input string: ')

# split word separated by sapce in enetered sentence
words = inStr.split(' ')

# traverse list of words anf find capitalized word
capitalWord = None
for word in words:
    if word.isupper()==True:
        capitalWord = word


# replace * with remaining letters of
#capital word after skipping first character
if capitalWord is not None:
  repl = capitalWord[1:]
  inStr = re.sub('[*]',repl,inStr)
  # join all words with space again and print them
  print ('Output sentence :')
  print (inStr)
```